# shapes disappearing when repeat tile is made

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, patterns

[repeat tile issue](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iOjDuiGYpDU)

I've attached a video of an issue I am having with vector/path/shapes disappearing when I make a repeat tile. Its confusing I feel to explain so the video would help to clarify my process.

[image]

The above image is the repeat tile I was working on. There are three tables in total within the repeat tile - its a hexagon shape. There is one table aligned to the top centre of the tile. To save this tile I 'created new pattern' and named it.
[image]

This is what the tile looks like as a pattern. I have used the appearance panel to give it a pink fill background. Note the table that was top centre of the tile now has the fries and cup shape/vector missing. It was visible when I saved the tile but for some reason it disappears once the pattern is made. I am perplexed.

Comment: Not logging in anywhere to view some random video. Even if it's Google.

Comment: Updated now with images

Comment: The video you provided is to the video inside your youtube studio (where you can make edits to the video.) Therefore we can't see it without having your log in details. Please provide the direct link to the public video.

Comment: I was able to extrapolate the correct link and edited the post. The link now brings you to the video without having to sign in anywhere.

Comment: But the idea of using repeating hexagons to make a fill which contains definitely something different than hexagons is a good one. Hopefully it gets fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess, which is all I can do without the EPS file to see for sure, but it looks like it's dropping off what is outside your shape.  I would guess that the burger is grouped, so the fact that even the little sliver of the burger is inside the shape is causing the whole to be included.  I would group the entire table and it's contents into one group, that should fix the problem.

Comment: Hmmmm seems like a strong possibility! I will try to see if it works thanks :)

Comment: Let us know if that worked or not.

Comment: Yes it worked :)